# Error on System.Linq.Enumerable.<TakeIterator>d__3a`1.MoveNext()

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I have the following code to iterate over subwebs of a sharepoint site.
If I debug it line by line, it never goes to  my catchs.

however on the uls logs I have this exception which I dont know what it means or if I should worry

```
53b416d1-1497-4b40-beb5-cd261180ece8 Stack trace:   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Created()    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.WebParts.LastCreatedJobs.LastCreatedJobs.<>c__DisplayClass8.<LoadGridData>b__7(SPWeb d)    
 at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)    
 at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)    
 at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()    
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.<TakeIterator>d__3a`1.MoveNext()    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.WebParts.LastCreatedJobs.LastCreatedJobs.<>c__DisplayClass8.<LoadGridData>b__5()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.WebParts.LastCreatedJobs.LastCreatedJobs.LoadGridData()    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.WebParts.LastCreatedJobs.LastCreatedJobs.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)    
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)    
 at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)    
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

My code is as follows

```
private void LoadGridData()
        {
            try
            {
                String currentUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;

                var jobInfoList = new List<JobInfo>();

                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                {
                    using (var clientSiteCollection = new SPSite(currentUrl))
                    {
                        foreach (
                            SPWeb web in
                                clientSiteCollection.AllWebs.AsSafeEnumerable().Where(
                                    c =>
                                    c.AllProperties[Constants.WebProperties.General.WebTemplate] != null &&
                                    c.AllProperties[Constants.WebProperties.General.WebTemplate].ToString() ==
                                    Constants.WebTemplates.JobWebPropertyName).OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).Take(5)
                            )
                        {
                            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName,
                                SPBasePermissions.Open))
                            {
                                SPList jobInfoListSp = web.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.Lists.JobInfoName);
                                if (jobInfoListSp != null)
                                {
                                    if (jobInfoListSp.Items.Count > 0)
                                    {
                                        var value =
                                            new SPFieldUrlValue(
                                                jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.iPowerLink].ToString());

                                        jobInfoList.Add(new JobInfo
                                        {
                                            JobName =
                                                jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.JobName].ToString(),
                                            JobCode =
                                                jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.JobCode].ToString(),
                                            IPowerLink = value.Url,
                                            JobWebsite = web.Url,
                                            IsConfidential =
                                                HelperFunctions.ConvertToBoolean(
                                                    jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.Confidential]
                                                        .ToString())
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            web.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                });

                _lastCreatedJobsGrid.DataSource = jobInfoList;
                _lastCreatedJobsGrid.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingService.LogError(LoggingCategory.Job, ex);
            }
        }



 public static class SPWebCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SPWeb> AsSafeEnumerable(this SPWebCollection webs)
        {
            foreach (SPWeb web in webs)
            {
                try
                {
                    yield return web;
                }
                finally
                {
                    web.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea what could be the cause and solution if needed?

**Update:**

I made the query on a variable first, and then the foreach, I also removed the AsSafeEnumerable
I wonder if I will have memoryleaks with this change?

**Update 2: When trying to use the code in the first answer which is impressive, I still get disposing problems.**

An

```
SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {96F3F1CB-DBD1-4514-AB9A-D49424AB0B6A}  This SPRequest was allocated
 at   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest..ctor()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_AllProperties()    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.WebParts.LastCreatedJobs.LastCreatedJobs.<>c__DisplayClass8.<LoadGridData>b__6(SPWeb c)    
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()    
 at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    
 at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.<GetEnumerator>d__0.MoveNext()    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.Extensions.Safe.<SafeTake>d__0`1.MoveNext()    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.WebParts.LastCreatedJobs.LastCreatedJobs.<>c__DisplayClass8.<LoadGridData>b__5()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.WebParts.LastCreatedJobs.LastCreatedJobs.LoadGridData()    
 at xx.SP.DMS.WebParts.WebParts.LastCreatedJobs.LastCreatedJobs.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
```

Comment: You haven't included the exception message.

Comment: oh yes its, its the first long part, thats the exception

Comment: That is a stacktrace not an exception message.

Comment: the ULS logs says unexpected, and shows only that, there is no Exception.Message I guess its because internally .net and not a sharepoint api exception

Comment: The stacktrace points at the `SPWeb.Created` getter. What is the logic inside it?

Comment: @L.V.SharepointArchitect That's the error message of the outer exception.  We need to know the error message of the *inner* exception.  Without it there's just no good way of knowing what is wrong, and thus what to look for.

Comment: its internal sharepoint, I cant get to whatever it does inside. I suppose with reflector I could, but anyway I cant modify its logic anyway, so I have to fix the caller code.

Comment: I have implemented as `SafeTake` method in my answer. With that the objects should not leak unless the `Where` or `OrderByDescending` throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is the `SPWeb` is getting disposed after invoking the `Enumerable.OrderByDescending`. This linq method is not lazy evaluated, so the `finally` block inside `AsSafeEnumerable` will get triggered.

Sample:

```
public class Disposed : IDisposable
{
    public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");
        IsDisposed = true;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<Disposed> GetDisposed()
{
    Func<Disposed> factory = () => new Disposed { Created = DateTime.Now };
    foreach(var f in Enumerable.Repeat(factory, 5))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In Enumerable");
        var item = f();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returning item");
            yield return item;
        }
        finally
        {
            item.Dispose();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Next iteration.");
    }
}
```

Usage 1:

```
foreach(var item in GetDisposed().Take(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.IsDisposed);
}

In Enumerable
Returning item
False
Disposed
Next iteration.
In Enumerable
Returning item
False
Disposed
Next iteration.
In Enumerable
Returning item
False
Disposed
Next iteration.
In Enumerable
Returning item
False
Disposed
Next iteration.
In Enumerable
Returning item
False
Disposed
```

Usage 2:

```
foreach(var item in GetDisposed().OrderByDescending(x => x.Created).Take(5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.IsDisposed);
}
```

Log:

```
In Enumerable
Returning item
Disposed
Next iteration.
In Enumerable
Returning item
Disposed
Next iteration.
In Enumerable
Returning item
Disposed
Next iteration.
In Enumerable
Returning item
Disposed
Next iteration.
In Enumerable
Returning item
Disposed
Next iteration.
True
True
True
True
True
```

Edit:

Here is an extension method to safely dispose objects not taken:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> SafeTake<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    int count
) where TSource : IDisposable
{
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if(--count >= 0)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        else if (item != null)
        {
            item.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> SafeWhere<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
) where TSource: IDisposable
{
    return source.SelectMany(x => {
        var result = predicate(x);
        if(!result && x != null) x.Dispose();
        return Enumerable.Repeat(x, result ? 1 : 0);
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (
    SPWeb web in
        clientSiteCollection.AllWebs.SafeWhere(
            c =>
            c.AllProperties[Constants.WebProperties.General.WebTemplate] != null &&
            c.AllProperties[Constants.WebProperties.General.WebTemplate].ToString() ==
            Constants.WebTemplates.JobWebPropertyName).OrderByDescending(d => d.Created).SafeTake(5)
    )
{
    try
    {
        if (!web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.Open)) continue;
        SPList jobInfoListSp = web.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.Lists.JobInfoName);
        if (jobInfoListSp == null) continue;
        if (0 >= jobInfoListSp.Items.Count) continue;

        var value =
            new SPFieldUrlValue(
                jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.iPowerLink].ToString());

        jobInfoList.Add(new JobInfo
        {
            JobName =
                jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.JobName].ToString(),
            JobCode =
                jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.JobCode].ToString(),
            IPowerLink = value.Url,
            JobWebsite = web.Url,
            IsConfidential =
                HelperFunctions.ConvertToBoolean(
                    jobInfoListSp.Items[0][Constants.FieldNames.Job.Confidential]
                        .ToString())
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        web.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: That would break his code, but wouldn't that break it later on in the application when he tries to use the disposed web, rather than inside the iterator?

Comment: I believe `OrderByDescending` is calling the `get_Created` on a disposed `SPWeb`.

Comment: @Servy I looked inside DotPeek and it appears that the target collection is transferred to an array and then sorted which would lead to this behavior.

Comment: Each web is disposed *when you ask for the one after it*.  While it's possible that that is where it's breaking, it's also possible that it's not, depending on some of the implementation details of `OrderBy` (namely when it performs the projection relative to when it asks for the next item, it could theoretically do either).

Comment: If that's true then yes, it would lead to this behavior.  Regardless, the iterator is very broken and needs fixing even if it's not the only problem.

Comment: so the problem is in the Take and not in the orderbydescending, correct?

Comment: @Romoku thanks a lot for your answer, however, after implementing it, I still have SPRequest problems, see Update Nr2 on my question.  How would you recommend to rewrite this?

Comment: If I put the AsSafeEnumerable, I dont get SPRequest errors but I get again the same error about Take!

Comment: Check my edit. I have implemented a `SafeWhere`. Unfortunately Linq and sharepoint do not seem to meet eye to eye. Some linq methods may need to be reimplemented to cope with `IDisposable`.

Comment: Since I am not a sharepoint developer it appears that I overlooked the  [Linq provider for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798478.aspx). I advise to use that since it probably handles all the disposing.

Comment: I do know the linq provider for sharepoint and its good but for queries with SPLists specially, where you need to generate a mapping file first with a console application SPMetal, in this case we are querying SPWebCollection objects which is not supported by that provider, your last edit just did great, I dont have SPRequest problems anymore, nor the weird stack trace